# Retrieving a Single Post From Google Reader

Tags: google-reader

I'm working on a Google Reader project that lists posts from a feed on a page.  From that page I would like to link to a new page that displays the contents of the selected post.  I see the id of the post is tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/1bf4b488adad6f1a but I don't see a call that I can use to directly retrieve it's contents.

Does anyone know of a solution other than getting all of the posts from the feed and searching for the correct one?

Comment: Are you using API calls (sending HTTP post or get requests to urls starting with http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/ and parsing back the results); or are you adding certain urls in web pages, which the users can click and will go directly into their Google Reader account, on that page?

Answer (score 0):

You could tag the item using /reader/api/0/edit-tag with some unique identifier, say the current Unix time, then retrieve all items with that tag (which is just that one item), then remove the tag. It's kind of a round-about way of doing it but as far as I know there is no API call to grab a single item by it's id.